# Which RPM Spec Macro provides OS Minor in Release, eg el8_4?

Tags: rhel, rpm, macro

How do I get the OS Minor in the Release field of the RPMs?

I understand that the spec file entry %{?dist} expands to the OS Major

```
    Name:     mypkg
    Version:  2.3
    Release:  1.2%{?dist}
    Arch:     noarch
```

and so the package is

```
    mypkg-2.3-1.2.el8.noarch
```

Which marco could I use so it also provides the OS Minor, eg

```
      mypkg-2.3-1.2.el8_4.noarch
```

thanks

Comment: Check this spec file: https://git.centos.org/rpms/firefox/blob/e30b24316597f543d4a14b25598682012bd42c01/f/SPECS/firefox.spec

Comment: Thanks  I tried that lua function rhel_minor_version and it returns -1 for me. I also tried the fragment  %{lua:print ( rpm.expand('%dist') )} and that returns .el8  What am i doing wrong?  thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have CentOS/RHEL 8 installed, so I cannot help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no macro giving the minor version of a release. When you see a version suffix such as `.el8_4`, that comes from a *build* which set `dist` to `.el8_4`.

As indicated by [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov), some packages do care about the minor version in use, and instead of explicitly checking for `.el8_4`, they parse `dist` to extract the components; see [Firefox](https://git.centos.org/rpms/firefox/blob/e30b24316597f543d4a14b25598682012bd42c01/f/SPECS/firefox.spec) for example.

Note that in most cases, you shouldn’t have to care about the minor version, and you shouldn’t try to produce a `.el8_4` RPM unless you have a reason to do so. Typically, an `.el8_4` RPM would be produced when it has a dependency change caused by other changes in 8.4.